# How to create a javascript post method that downloads a file, but can also handle a json response

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, json

*Edit*

added a line to hash the password in the **example** so people don't get distracted.

---

I have a server-side php file that checks posts parameters for validation purposes and downloads a dynamically generated file if the parameters are valid. If the parameters are invalid the php returns json with the reason why. I can't seem to find a way to call my php from javascript and handle both cases.

My php looks something like this(simplified):

---

***PHP***

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['Username']) && isset($_POST['Password']))
     {

     $dbPassword = *sql statement*
     $password = hash("sha256", $_POST['Password']);

     if($dbPassword==$password)
     {

     header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
     header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= 'somefile.zip');
     header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
     header('Expires: 0');
     header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
     header('Pragma: public');
     header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('somefile.zip'));
     ob_clean();
     flush(); 
     $bytesRead = readfile('somefile.zp');


    }
    else
    {

    $returnArray = array();

    $returnArray['Status']='Invalid'

    return json_encode[$returnArray];

    }

    }
?>
```

---

I have tried this with an a href link using GET which downloads the file but also downloads the json as a text file, which is not what I want. I would also prefer to user POST.

The second method I tried was using a form post which downloads but I don't know if its possible to get a json response with this method.

---

***Javascript***

```
function submitform()
{

var theForm = document.forms['myForm'];

    theForm.setAttribute("method", "post");
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'hidden';
    input.name = "UserName";
    input.value = "someuser";
    theForm.appendChild(input);
    theForm.submit();
}
```

---

Lastly I've tried using ajax and while i get back the file data, i dont' know if its possible to make the browser download it as a file. What i've read suggests that you can't.

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text.**

Comment: You won't be able to force a download via ajax. You can return a JSON containing a error message if failed and the download URL in case os success, then you redirect the user to the URL (wich will start the download without leaving the current page).

Comment: @SLaks i'm not even using passwords in my actual php, the php is just a simplified example of what i'm doing, which you would have known if you had read my question

Comment: @Hisamu Yup I know you can do this, but I was hoping to have the validation check in the php which generates the file, so some random person cannot call my php with a url.